# Remote Connections Mysql Ubuntu - bind address failed

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am trying to configure my server to allow remote connections.

From what I understand I need to uncomment bind-address 127.0.0.1 in the my.cnf file, then restart mysql.

That hasn't worked.

I have also tried changing it to bind-address 0.0.0.0.

That hasn't worked either.

When I try to remotely connect using SQLpro, I get the following error:

MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '54.444.33.4' (4)

Can anybody offer any other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: log sould tell you whether mysql listens on this ip. you could also check this with `netstat -an | grep 3306`

Comment: firewall rules?

Comment: 3306 tcp 0.0.0.0/0, 85.33.93.54/32

Comment: Does the user you're trying to connect with have grants from that IP? Or including that IP, if wildcarded?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind MySQL to the IP on which it should be reachable.

> bind-address = 192.168.1.50

Then you connect to this address

> mysql -p -u someUser -h 192.168.1.50

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: But would this mean that localhost would no longer be able to connect it its own database?

Comment: Hi. I tried it out & it works just fine. Mind you can of course use bind-address = all which is the same as bind-address = 0.0.0.0